# Stuck with excel function with SUMIF and concatenate

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I found a nice tutorial on making burndown and burnup charts. I just cant get the same functions to work no matter what I try. Seems like there is a difference between excel 2007 and 2010 on how the function must be written??
The tutorial: http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/02/video-how-to-create-burndown-charts-for.html

Basically im just trying to add numbers. Each row have column with a random number and a column that shows the total of the numbers until that row. So the last row will show the total of all the numbers. Row number 5 will only show the total of the numbers from row 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. I hope it makes sense :)

The function according to the tutorial:

```
=SUMIF([Created Date],CONCATENATE("<=",Table_owssvr_1[[#This Row],[Released]]),[Points])
```

But when I paste it into my own excel workbook it gives an error. From what I can see, I have to change the "," with ";". The "#This Row" is not regonized but my best guess is that it has to be replaced with "@".

This is as close as I can get:

```
=SUMIF([Oprettet dato]; CONCATENATE("<=";Table2[@];[Sprint start]);[Estimat])
```

Is it because of the difference between 2007 and 2010 or am I just too much of a noob?? :)

Comment: That notation is for formatted tables.  Go to insert, hit table.

Comment: I am using a table so I dont think thats the problem.

Comment: [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=86740896f1da5419&resid=86740896F1DA5419!592&parid=86740896F1DA5419!591&authkey=!AJ-7Vn9gaRaxgv4)
Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

In Office 2010 the `[#This Row]` notation has been condensed to improve the user experience.  The `[#This Row]` notation has been replaced with an `@` notation in formulas and, where possible, the requirement for explicit table name references in the formula have been removed.

```
=SUMIF([Oprettet Date]; CONCATENATE("<=";[@Sprint start]);[@Estimat])
```

Note, using `;` enstead of `,` is regional settings specific

---

**In responce to comment**: sorry, an extra row ref slipped in, try this

```
=SUMIF([Oprettet Date]; CONCATENATE("<=";[@Sprint start]);[Estimat])
```

Comment: That almost worked. Instead of adding the value of the numbers, it starts with the total in the first row and then subtracts the number for each row.
When I try to write what you suggested, excel automatically correts it to
=SUMIF([Oprettet Date]; CONCATENATE("<=";[@[Sprint start]]);[@Estimat])

Comment: Excel keeps changing [@Sprint start] to [@[Sprint start]] but maybe thats okay.
When using
=SUMIF([Oprettet Date]; CONCATENATE("<=";[@[Sprint start]]);[Estimat])
each row gets the total number of all rows instead.